# Android Studio freezes/hangs when i try to open anything

Tags: java, android

Recently I upgraded my Android Studio to 3.1 and also my gradle to 4.4.

Since then android studio doesn't let me open anything. (Any project , any file location, etc). I am able to create a new project but if try opening an existing one it just freezes. And then I have to kill it through Task Manager.

[image]

I am also able to open the settings page through welcome wizard. There also I tried to change the gradle version manually, again while browsing to the location it just gets hanged. Same way as above

I tried upgrading the Java version, installing/uninstalling android studio and everything else I can but its the same.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Upgrade it to 3.1.1. Android 3.1 had some freezing issues, especially when you clicked Build Variants

Comment: In your task manager, when trying to open an existing project, check how much memory android studio is taking.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar issue.  Please check the system Environment Variable, the JAVA_HOME path should be set correctly according to Java installed in your PC; something like this in my PC  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172"

This resolved the issue for me.

Cheers!

Herbs